# What should be the right attitude towards voting comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-votes

There is no denying that voting posts is critical to the community, but what about voting comments? Is this less serious?

Say, if I asked someone to elaborate his/her answer by leaving a comment, is it appreciate to upvote his/her response simply to express my thanks?

Comment: You should upvote the comment if you think it is an useful contribution. If the contribution is integral to the post, it should perhaps be edited into the post.

Comment: The tooltip says: "this comment adds something useful to the post" - so yes, in that case an upvote is fine.

Answer (score 7):

Vote on comments if they add something useful to the post.

If you asked someone to elaborate their answer, and their comment explains it... by all means upvote.
Depending on circumstance, you may also want to edit the content from the comment into the post. Consider that the OP apparently chose not to do this.

People also vote for comments that they find funny. Technically we shouldn't do that, but comment upvotes don't grant rep, and therefore don't give extra privileges. The only thing to be gotten from upvoted comments are a few badges. So upvoting a funny comment usually isn't harmful.

Keep in mind that when a post has a lot of comments, it will only show the ones with the most upvotes. In this case, you may want to be careful with voting for fun comments, and make sure they don't drown the actually useful comments.

Answer (score 3):

> Say, if I asked someone to elaborate his/her answer by leaving a comment, is it appreciate to upvote his/her response simply to express my thanks?

Well, no. Comments pointing out things that have since been fixed, and comments saying "thanks for pointing that out" and "see edit" are just noise after you got notified of them. Remove yours, and flag theirs for being obsolete. Just upvote the answer if the edit made the answer better.

And if there are a lot of comments, flag the post itself instead and tell a mod that all comments are now obsolete. Unless of course you're planning to run for moderator yourself, and want to impress people with your flag count: in that case flag each comment individually.

Answer (score 2):

This basically falls under the more generic question "when do you vote on a comment?". Like content voting this is very personal; in the context of comments its perfectly reasonable to never vote on a comment at all. Here is what I do.

- I vote on comments I think are potential targets to become an answer
- I vote on comments that I think need to be read by others; be it the content author or just everyone
- When it is a comment in response to me, I tend to vote on the comment if I agree with it as a silent way of communicating that. This is basically me under the delusion that the other party will actually see it and understand the vote came from me, which in all likelihood will not be the case. This it is mostly for my own gains, it makes me feel better.

And that's basically all it is - what I mean by my comment votes is that I *support* the comment for what it is trying to convey/achieve. But comments indeed are of less importance than actual content so I don't go actively looking for comments to vote on. Its a good thing to do when you're triggered to read comments, while you're at it.